# How to texture a sphere in PyQt5 QOpenGLWidget

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, textures, opengl-compat

I'm trying to display a map of the world in a program I've made using PyQt5. For the rendering stuff so far this is the (mostly borrowed) code I have:

```
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QOpenGLVersionProfile
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QWidget)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.glWidget = GLWidget()

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.img = Image.open("BWTopo.png")
        self.mapWidth, self.mapHeight = self.img.size
        pgImData = np.asarray(self.img)
        self.inputMapFile = np.flipud(pgImData)

        self.setWindowTitle("SPHERE")


class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.object = 0
        self.xRot = 0
        self.yRot = 0
        self.zRot = 0

        self.lastPos = QPoint()

        self.main = QColor.fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.clear = QColor.fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)

    def setXRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.xRot:
            self.xRot = angle
            self.update()

    def setYRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.yRot:
            self.yRot = angle
            self.update()

    def setZRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.zRot:
            self.zRot = angle
            self.update()

    def initializeGL(self):
        version_profile = QOpenGLVersionProfile()
        version_profile.setVersion(2, 0)
        self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions(version_profile)
        self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()

        self.setClearColor(self.clear.darker())
        self.object = self.makeObject()
        self.gl.glShadeModel(self.gl.GL_FLAT)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_CULL_FACE)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_LIGHTING)
        self.gl.glLightModelfv(self.gl.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0])
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
        self.gl.glColorMaterial(self.gl.GL_FRONT, self.gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)

    def paintGL(self):
        self.gl.glClear(self.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | self.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        self.gl.glCallList(self.object)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        self.gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                side)

        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glOrtho(-0.5, +0.5, +0.5, -0.5, 4.0, 15.0)
        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        dx = event.x() - self.lastPos.x()
        dy = event.y() - self.lastPos.y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setYRotation(self.yRot + 8 * dx)
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setZRotation(self.zRot + 8 * dx)

        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def makeObject(self):
        genList = self.gl.glGenLists(1)
        self.gl.glNewList(genList, self.gl.GL_COMPILE)

        self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_TRIANGLES)

        
        UResolution = 18
        VResolution = 36
        r = 0.3
        startU = 0
        startV = 0
        endU = math.pi * 2
        endV = math.pi
        stepU = (endU-startU)/UResolution # step size between U-points on the grid
        stepV = (endV-startV)/VResolution # step size between V-points on the grid
        for i in range(UResolution):  # U-points
            for j in range(VResolution):  # V-points
                u = i*stepU+startU
                v = j*stepV+startV
                un = endU if (i+1==UResolution) else (i+1)*stepU+startU
                vn = endV if (j+1==VResolution) else (j+1)*stepV+startV
                
                p0 = [ math.cos(u)*math.sin(v)*r, math.cos(v)*r, math.sin(u)*math.sin(v)*r ]
                p1 = [ math.cos(u)*math.sin(vn)*r, math.cos(vn)*r, math.sin(u)*math.sin(vn)*r ] 
                p2 = [ math.cos(un)*math.sin(v)*r, math.cos(v)*r, math.sin(un)*math.sin(v)*r ]
                p3 = [ math.cos(un)*math.sin(vn)*r, math.cos(vn)*r, math.sin(un)*math.sin(vn)*r ]

                # Output the first triangle of this grid square
                self.gl.glVertex3f(p0[0],p0[1],p0[2])
                self.gl.glVertex3f(p2[0],p2[1],p2[2])
                self.gl.glVertex3f(p1[0],p1[1],p1[2])

                # Output the other triangle of this grid square
                self.gl.glVertex3f(p3[0],p3[1],p3[2])
                self.gl.glVertex3f(p1[0],p1[1],p1[2])
                self.gl.glVertex3f(p2[0],p2[1],p2[2])
                

        self.gl.glEnd()
        self.gl.glEndList()

        return genList

    def normalizeAngle(self, angle):
        while angle < 0:
            angle += 360 * 16
        while angle > 360 * 16:
            angle -= 360 * 16
        return angle

    def setClearColor(self, c):
        self.gl.glClearColor(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

    def setColor(self, c):
        self.gl.glColor4f(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It creates an unshaded sphere in a window. I want to apply the image loaded in from "BWTopo" as an equirectangular projected map onto the sphere. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a texture object:

```py
self.gl.glActiveTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE0)
self.text_obj = self.gl.glGenTextures(1)
self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.text_obj)
self.gl.glPixelStorei(self.gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
self.gl.glTexImage2D(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, self.gl.GL_RGB, self.mapWidth, self.mapHeight, 0, self.gl.GL_RGB, self.gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.inputMapFile.tobytes())
self.gl.glPixelStorei(self.gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4)
self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)
self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)
```

You need to create the texture coordinates in range [0, 1]:

```py
t0 = [i/UResolution, 1-j/VResolution]
t1 = [i/UResolution, 1-(j+1)/VResolution]
t2 = [(i+1)/UResolution, 1-j/VResolution]
t3 = [(i+1)/UResolution, 1-(j+1)/VResolution]

# Output the first triangle of this grid square
self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t0)
self.gl.glVertex3f(*p0)
self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t2)
self.gl.glVertex3f(*p2)
self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t1)
self.gl.glVertex3f(*p1)

# Output the other triangle of this grid square
self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t3)
self.gl.glVertex3f(*p3)
self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t1)
self.gl.glVertex3f(*p1)
self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t2)
self.gl.glVertex3f(*p2)
```

Two-dimensional texturing has to be enabled, see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml) and the texture object needs to be bound before drawing the mesh:

```py
self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D) 
self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.text_obj)
self.gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
self.gl.glCallList(self.object)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QOpenGLVersionProfile
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.glWidget = GLWidget()
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("SPHERE")

class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.object = 0
        self.xRot = 0
        self.yRot = 0
        self.zRot = 0

        self.lastPos = QPoint()

        self.main = QColor.fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.clear = QColor.fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0)

        self.img = Image.open("BWTopo.png")
        #self.img = Image.open("worldmap1.bmp")
        self.mapWidth, self.mapHeight = self.img.size
        pgImData = np.asarray(self.img)
        self.inputMapFile = np.flipud(pgImData)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)

    def setXRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.xRot:
            self.xRot = angle
            self.update()

    def setYRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.yRot:
            self.yRot = angle
            self.update()

    def setZRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.zRot:
            self.zRot = angle
            self.update()

    def initializeGL(self):
        version_profile = QOpenGLVersionProfile()
        version_profile.setVersion(2, 0)
        self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions(version_profile)
        self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()

        self.setClearColor(self.clear.darker())
        self.object = self.makeObject()
        self.gl.glShadeModel(self.gl.GL_SMOOTH)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_CULL_FACE)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_LIGHTING)
        self.gl.glLightModelfv(self.gl.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0])
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
        self.gl.glColorMaterial(self.gl.GL_FRONT, self.gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
        
        self.gl.glActiveTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE0)
        self.text_obj = self.gl.glGenTextures(1)
        self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.text_obj)
        self.gl.glPixelStorei(self.gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        self.gl.glTexImage2D(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, self.gl.GL_RGB, self.mapWidth, self.mapHeight, 0, self.gl.GL_RGB, self.gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.inputMapFile.tobytes())
        self.gl.glPixelStorei(self.gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4)
        self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)
        self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)
        
    def paintGL(self):
        self.gl.glClear(self.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | self.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D) 
        self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.text_obj)
        self.gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
        self.gl.glCallList(self.object)
        
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        self.gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                side)

        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glOrtho(-0.5, +0.5, +0.5, -0.5, 4.0, 15.0)
        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        dx = event.x() - self.lastPos.x()
        dy = event.y() - self.lastPos.y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setYRotation(self.yRot + 8 * dx)
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setZRotation(self.zRot + 8 * dx)

        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def makeObject(self):
        genList = self.gl.glGenLists(1)
        self.gl.glNewList(genList, self.gl.GL_COMPILE)
        self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_TRIANGLES)

        UResolution = 18
        VResolution = 36
        r = 0.3
        startU = 0
        startV = 0
        endU = math.pi * 2
        endV = math.pi
        stepU = (endU-startU)/UResolution # step size between U-points on the grid
        stepV = (endV-startV)/VResolution # step size between V-points on the grid
        for i in range(UResolution):  # U-points
            for j in range(VResolution):  # V-points
                u = i*stepU+startU
                v = j*stepV+startV
                un = endU if (i+1==UResolution) else (i+1)*stepU+startU
                vn = endV if (j+1==VResolution) else (j+1)*stepV+startV

                p0 = [ math.cos(u)*math.sin(v)*r, math.cos(v)*r, math.sin(u)*math.sin(v)*r ]
                p1 = [ math.cos(u)*math.sin(vn)*r, math.cos(vn)*r, math.sin(u)*math.sin(vn)*r ] 
                p2 = [ math.cos(un)*math.sin(v)*r, math.cos(v)*r, math.sin(un)*math.sin(v)*r ]
                p3 = [ math.cos(un)*math.sin(vn)*r, math.cos(vn)*r, math.sin(un)*math.sin(vn)*r ]

                t0 = [i/UResolution, 1-j/VResolution]
                t1 = [i/UResolution, 1-(j+1)/VResolution]
                t2 = [(i+1)/UResolution, 1-j/VResolution]
                t3 = [(i+1)/UResolution, 1-(j+1)/VResolution]

                # Output the first triangle of this grid square
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t0)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p0)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t2)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p2)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t1)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p1)

                # Output the other triangle of this grid square
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t3)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p3)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t1)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p1)
                self.gl.glTexCoord2f(*t2)
                self.gl.glVertex3f(*p2)

        self.gl.glEnd()
        self.gl.glEndList()

        return genList

    def normalizeAngle(self, angle):
        while angle < 0:
            angle += 360 * 16
        while angle > 360 * 16:
            angle -= 360 * 16
        return angle

    def setClearColor(self, c):
        self.gl.glClearColor(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

    def setColor(self, c):
        self.gl.glColor4f(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, when I use the code you gave in the program it finishes without displaying anything. Is that a problem on my end?

Comment: @Drickken I've added my full, well-running example to the question.